# jQuery: Create element using text from another element

Tags: jquery

For design purposes, I'm wanting to create a new div with the text from another h2. But if I have multiple instances on a page, it's not duplicating the related h2. I'm duplicating the same one over and over. Here's the html:

```
<div class="addOutline">
  <div>
    <h2 class="heading-title">
      First Heading
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="addOutline">
  <div>
    <h2 class="heading-title">
      Second Heading
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my broke JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var text = $(".addOutline h2.heading-title").text();
  $('.addOutline').append('<div class="outlineHeader horizontal">' + text + '</div>');
})
```

Desired HTML output:

```
<div class="addOutline">
  <div>
    <h2 class="heading-title">
      First Heading
    </h2>
    <div class="outlineHeader horizontal">First Heading</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="addOutline">
  <div>
    <h2 class="heading-title">
      Second Heading
    </h2>
    <div class="outlineHeader horizontal">Second Heading</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yzL1k7pr/1/

Comment: multiple instances ?? post HTML for multiple instances.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68827081/edit) to show the intended HTML structure after the code has executed.

Comment: @kmoser updated with intended HTML output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think do you want this :

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
    $('.addOutline').each(function(i,v){
        var text = $(this).find("h2.heading-title").text();
        $(this).find('div').append('<div class="outlineHeader horizontal">' + text + '</div>');
    });
});
```

Check it, it will help you : https://jsfiddle.net/yzL1k7pr/1/